# @Transactional rollback is not working in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am having a requirement where i need to insert some employee data into db2 database and below is the code for that :

```
@Log4j2
@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl extends EmployeeService{

@Autowired
private EmployeeDataRepository employeeDataRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(rollbackOn = {DataAccessException.class})
public void insertEmployeeData(List<Employee> employeeList){
 try{
     employeeDataRepository.insertEmployeeData(employeeList);
    }catch(DataAccessException ex){
      log.error("Exception whie inserting data in db {}",ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

```
@Log4j2
@Repository
public class EmployeeDataRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeDataRepository{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${db.schema}")
private String schema;

@Override
public void insertEmployeeData(List<Employee> employeeList){
   this.jdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("Employee");
   for(Employee emp : employeeList){
    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
      parameters.put("name", emp.name);
      parameters.put("age", emp.age);
      parameters.put("dateOfJoining", emp.dateOfJoining);
      parameters.put("address", emp.address);
      parameters.put("salary", emp.salary);
      jdbcInsert.execute(parameters);
      log.info("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age + " dateOfJoining = "+dateOfJoining);
      }
      return;
}

}
```

using spring datasource properties datasource is configured and injected into `EmployeeDataRepositoryImpl` class. I am using `SimpleJdbcInsert` to insert data into db2 table. For transnational handling i am using 
`@Transactional(rollbackOn = {DataAccessException.class})` on method. When the data is inserted one by one then if something goes wrong at db level then it should rollback but eventually its not happening. Also i tried putting annotation at class level but there is no luck. Please let me know if i am missing anything ?

Comment: how do you know the exception thrown is of the type `DataAccessException` ? maybe the exception thrown is of a different type ?

Comment: I even tried with @Transactional(rollbackOn = {Exception.class}) also. And also whatever the exception coming that only i have put in try catch block and its coming there in catch block.

Comment: wait? you are catching the exception and not re-throwing it?

Comment: no i am not re-throwing it just logging the error message as i have the requirement like that.

Comment: then if you are handling the transaction, the framework will not rollback - you can log and re-throw the exception.  Swallowing the exception like that is typically not desirable as it hides the root of the issue (only visible in logs) - even if you are going to log, you do not want print just the message but the entire stack trace so you get all the necessary information to fix it

Comment: ohh than in that case is there any alternative to rollback the transaction ?

Comment: you would want to log and re-throw (so the rollback clause of the transaction takes hold)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i will try doing that. But i am not getting the vote up option .

Comment: Your code is flawed, you shouldn't be catching the dataaccessexeption as that is the key to rolling back things. If spring doesn't see the exception nothing will be rolled back. Also make sure you are using a database that supports transactions! If you use MySQL with MyISAM tables there is no transaction support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having a couple of things mixed up here.

1. Spring rolls your transaction back, if a (Runtime)exception **bubbles through your @Transactional method.**
2. You are catching the DataAccessException exception, hence **preventing** the rollback.
3. There is also no need to specify the exception in rollbackOn.

Your code should read like this, this is enough.

```
@Transactional
public void insertEmployeeData(List<Employee> employeeList){
  employeeDataRepository.insertEmployeeData(employeeList);
}
```

For more information on how @Transactional works, see [this link.](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth)

Comment: Hi Marco just wanted to know than what's the purpose of rollbackOn or rollbackFor ?

Comment: You could use rollbackOn (javax. @Transactional) /rollbackFor (Spring @Transactional) if you wanted to rollback on checked exceptions (business-exceptions), because by default Spring only rolls back on RuntimeExceptions. So "rollbackFor=MyCheckedBusinessException.class"). For any other RuntimeExceptions you do not need that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try rollBackFor instead of rollBackOn

As per below link:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12709

Comment: Hi @Hariharan. Thanks for your first contribution to SO. To make it more useful, explain the reasoning for your suggestion.

Comment: There was a mention in this link about rollBackFor https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12709

Comment: Thanks for the update. You can edit your answer to include it directly, in the body of the text. It will increase the chances readers will see it.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing you can do: links tend to become stale. A summary of what is in the link would help. See [tips on how to give a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more.